# Открыть Navigation rail Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Я недавно изучил Котлин и наткнулся на такую проблему как мне сделать navigation rail так чтобы оно открывалась как на этом фото[image: Это на Flutter я хочу в Kotlin]

Comment: Не думаю что именно Котлин вам тут поможет. Изучайте Android SDK, animations, Jetpack UI. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/explorer?case=ui

Comment: Маловато информации для ответа. Kotlin тут вообще не причём, а приведённая вами картинка - скорее всего чей-то кастомный контрол. Если нет либы под это - надо просто вручную всё написать, сформулировав однозначное ТЗ. Без однозначного ТЗ мы не сможем вам помочь, т.к. картинка им не является.

Comment: Вам, [например сюда](https://github.com/zirouan/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign)

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент Navigation rail находится в стадии beta на андроид. Это не мешает его использовать, имплементацию можно посмотреть тут https://material.io/components/navigation-rail/android